# Is this usage of synchronizedMap thread safe?

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety, linkedhashmap

I have a singleton class, that has a map which can be accessed by multiple threads at the same time. Could somebody please check the code below and tell me if its thread safe?
(note: I dont plan to use ConcurrentHashMap, and the printMap method is called only seldom.)

```
    public  class MySingleton{

      private Map<String,String>  cache = Collections.synchronizedMap(
new LinkedHashMap<String,String>());

      public String getValue(String key){
         return cache.get(key)
      }

      public void setValue(String key, String value){
         cache.put(key, value);
      }

      public void printMap(){
          synchronized(cache){

              for(Entry<String,String> entry: cache.entrySet()){
                    println('key: '+entry.getKey()+', value: ' + value);

               }
          }

      }
    }
```

My test is working... but i am doubting if this code is good enough to be called 'thread safe'.

points that I considered:

1. The readValue and putValue methods don't need to have a 'synchronized' block since i am using a synchronizedMap
2. printMap should have the synchronized block, since the javadoc for says that we should synchronize the Map instance before each iteration. 
   http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Being a bit picky here, but is that class actually a singleton?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's okay. The key thing is that while you're iterating, nothing will be able to modify the map because `cache.put` will end up synchronizing on `cache` anyway.

*Personally* I'd rather make that explicit, by using a "normal" hashmap and synchronizing on the same object (whether the map or something else) from all three methods - but what you've got should be fine.

(Alternatively, you could use `ConcurrentHashMap` to start with. It's worth at least looking at that.)

Comment: actually when I looked at the code, the cache.put was synchronizing on a internal object called mutex.   not itself.  any thoughts?

Comment: @rk2010: Look in the constructor: `mutex = this;`

Comment: I am really liking your normal hash map idea... !

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is thread safe. Each access to the cache is synchronized (by the synchronizedMap for get and set and by an explicit sync block for the printMap)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this class is thread-safe.

Though note that even a thread-safe class requires *safe publication* to be used really safely (without safe publication nothing guarantees that other threads can't see `cache` in non-initialized state, i.e. `null`).

But in this case you can eliminate a need in safe publication by making your class immutable (`final` keyword guarantees that other threads can't see `null` in `cache`):

```
private final Map<String,String>  cache = Collections.synchronizedMap( new LinkedHashMap<String,String>());
```